# 4 way toggle sometimes not toggling up/down reliably compared to other switches

Tags: electrical, switch, multiway-switch

I purchased these Leviton 4-way switches and replaced older ones, along with some 3-way switches on the same circuit. The switches are in a series of two 3-ways, and one 4-way switch. The switches all work correctly in the various combinations of the switches being in the up/down positions, except for an issue with the 4-way toggle position getting somewhat "stuck", as described below.

But, the 4 way switches appear different, likely because they're commercial grade. The 4-way switches, when in the up position, are almost horizontal. My concern is that sometimes when horizontal, the other 3 way switches are not functioning (flipping the 3-ways up/down have no effect on the light). This is remedied by putting the 4-way in the opposite position so it's not horizontal.

It's been a few months, but I recall the 4-way switch's toggle behavior/positioning being this way before installing them at all, so I don't think it's an issue with the wall plate.

What's going on here with the toggle? How do I fix this?

4-way switch in down position:
[image]

4-way in up position, almost horizontal
[image]

4 way in up position, pushed up a bit with my finger
[image]

3 way switch, with rectangle "casing" around toggle. Fully in up position
[image]

4-way toggle: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B000FKF7NU/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000FKF7NU)

Comment: Courtesy embed - makes it easier for everyone instead of having to click links to see the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those look like defective switches to me. If they continue that behavior with the plate removed, the switches are defective and need to be replaced. Toggle light switches should always snap cleanly to the top and bottom position, without requiring you to hold them in place or push them extra at either end.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the wall plate to test it out, and there was no change to the toggle. Surprised since I thought Leviton was super reliable, and that's the brand I used for outlets, single pole, and 3-way switches.

Comment: I suspect you may have gotten a switch that has a Center Off function somehow

Comment: Also possible @ThreePhaseEel but it seems unlikely since they are far more expensive at my local electrical distributor, and they always return to center. It's a fun theory though.

Comment: I replaced the switches and all is well now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be that much of a gap between faceplate and switch as you have on the 4-way switches. If you take off the faceplate, I think you will find that the box is a bit inset from the wall. You should either remount it so that it is flush with the outer surface or add an extender such as [this one from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/ReceptXtenders-1-2-in-1-Gang-Electrical-Receptacle-Box-Extension-Ring-00004/100159668):

[image: 1/2" single gang plastic extension]

Comment: Sorry, I realized I took a picture of a regular single pole switch for that last one. However, the 3-ways look the same with the border, except of course not displaying on/off.

Comment: @Ruskes It was three sentences, but I deleted the other 2 based on OP's comment. FYI, while I often ramble on (not just in StackExchange), I am also (in)famous for my one word emails: "Done"

Comment: and you can be funny

Comment: I replaced the 4 way switches with regular residential ones and the gap was no longer there. Did not require the extender.